# Select box onChange event

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am little confused about this: How can you trigger the javascript event `onChange` of a select box if there is only one option in it?

Comment: If there is only one element then why you need change?

Comment: i want to show a div when the default value is selected. but now i have only the default value how i will show that div?

Comment: I guess, he means an empty, that is by default and one more.

Comment: @baig772 just show it all the time if only one default value is present. Or just do on change and add callback function, that will check if value or text is not empty.

Comment: @baig772 if you have only one element then you can prepend select to the dropdown and it will allow you to fire change event

Comment: add a default option like Select...

Comment: @baig772 Show a `div` by default if applicable. Also to trigger event function (functions) in native JS you can try to use `dispatchEvent` (MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) and `fireEvent` (IE, MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thnx @khaled_webdev now working fine :)

Comment: now how to mark the question solved?

Comment: i have added my answer @baig772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a default empty option like Select...

```
<select>
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option value="val_1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one value, it won't change, but if they focus on it, and then click out of it, the `onBlur` event will trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Was that what you needed? http://jsfiddle.net/j3Xga/1/ I know this is not a jQuery question.